# Place picture in ModernCV?

Tags: moderncv

I have already seen some questions and answers related to my question. However, they did not solve my problem. Therefore, I am asking this question.

I am using the `moderncv` template, style `classic` and I wish to add my profile picture. However, the default setting gives me this:

[image]

However, I want the profile pic to be at the left side below the name (I don't need the resume title and I can just comment that) as given in this template:

[image]

So only the profile picture should be at the left and the name and other details should be at the right.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewrite the head for style `classic` completely. We have to rewrite command `\makecvtitle`.

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{green} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value

\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
% recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
\recomputecvlengths%
% optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
\def\phonesdetails{}%
\collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
\protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
\def\socialsdetails{}%
\collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
\protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
\newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
\savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
\addressfont\color{color2}%
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}%
\makenewline
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
  \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
  \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
\end{tabular}}%
% optional photo (pre-rendering)
\newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
\savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
 {}%
  {%
   \setlength\fboxrule{\@photoframewidth}%
   \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
     \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
   {\color{color1}\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}
  }%
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
\vspace*{0pt}
\raggedright\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\vspace*{0pt}%
\raggedleft\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@familyname}\\
\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of
\end{minipage}%
%   \raggedleft\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@lastname}}%\familyname
\\[.5em]%
%{\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\null\hfill\titlestyle{\@title}}\\[2.5em]%
% optional quote
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
{}%
{{\null\hfill\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\hfill\null\\[2.5em]}}%
\par}%
\makeatother

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description 
  no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description 
  line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore 
  normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation 
  when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

\end{document}
```

and the resulting pdf:

[image]